# php mysqli prepared statement remove query issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have made a page to remove different elements of my site, but for some reason it's not working... Event though i set the `fMenu` to be i - integer, because it is.
When i run the code below, it gives me:

**Fatal error**: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in **C:\Users\joonas\Desktop\Le Kerouac\root\admin\remove.php** on line **44**

Code(PHP):

```
include_once('../php/connDbPrepared.php');
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');
//Anti mysql injection precautions
$menu = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $menu);
$sql = "REMOVE FROM menu WHERE fMenu = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $menu);
if($stmt->execute())
{
    $stmt->close();
    echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.replace("../admin/admintable.php?page=main&message=removeSuccessMenu");
    </script>
    ';
}
else
{
    echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
        $("#closePopup").click(function()
        {
            $("#screenCover").slideToggle("slow");
            setTimeout(resetPage, 600);
        });
});
function resetPage()
{
    window.location.replace("../admin/admintable.php?page=main");
}
</script>
<div id="screenCover" style="display:none;">
<div id="popup">
<div id="closePopupMain">
<p id="closePopup"><a href="#">X</a></p>
</div>
<p id="failure">Le menu n\'a pas éte enlevée! Cause: Erreur '.mysqli_errno($mysqli).": ".mysqli_error($mysqli).'</p>
</div>
</div>';
}
```

Comment: Your script lacks error handling. With error handling you'd probably have found the error yourself rather quickly. At least activate the exceptions if you're not willing to test the return value of each single call to a mysqli function/method. see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no REMOVE keyword in mysql, use DELETE :

`Delete from menu where fmenu = ?`

Answer (score -2):

The correct function name is [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) not `bind_param()`

Change

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $menu);
```

to

```
$stmt->bindParam("i", $menu);
```

This will get rid of the error message that you are getting. Then you need to fix your SQL statement.

Comment: He/she is using MySQLi, not PDO. It's [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Just query is failing due to wrong syntax.

Comment: ah, you are correct. my brain just goes to PDO by defualt. Downvote appropriately earned.

Comment: Understandable. Somehow I feel like bad person now :s

Comment: Gotta keep the quality of the site somehow. My net change on this post is 0 with my edit, so don't feel bad. I'd delete my post, but I haven't earned the peer pressure badge yet >.>

Comment: Just wanted to recommend that badge :) Plus one on comment :)